# issue with URL validation MVC razor and JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on MVC Razor. I face an issue to validate URL validation.

I need to do URL validation before inserting in temp DB.

I got a reference of http://www.regxlib.com/Search.aspx?k=&c=2&m=-1&ps=20

and found one nice validation pattern,

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

While i work in MVC view, it gives me error so i have change it to

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

i.e.

`@@` instead of `@`

when it runs and if i see the console, i got the original one, so i think it is okay for me to do 
`@@` instead of `@`

But in console i got an error

[image]

can anyone tell me what is wrong with this, so got the error,

***"invalid range in character class"***

Comment: Not an answer as such, but those two "&amp;" aren't actually supposed to be "&amp;", but just "&" - they've been HTML-encoded once too often by the website you got the regex from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to fix this: In the javascript validator, remove `new RegExp()` as well as the quotes, and add slashes at beginning and end, indicating a regex literal. Because your Regex is in a string, "\" is interpreted as a string escape, rather than a regex escape, essentially meaning all the "\" will be removed. You avoid that by not using a string, but a javascript regex literal:

```
var urlregex = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&/~\+#])?/;
```

If creating the expression using RegExp(), you'd have to use `\\` in every place `\` occurs.

As mentioned in the comment, replace two `&amp;` with `&` (double HTML encode on server you got the regex from). They're not wrong in Regex syntax, but they do make the expression allow for `;`, which isn't allowed in a URL.

**Update/explanation**

The actual meaning of the error is that because javascript ignores all the backslashes in the string when creating the final regex, it turns into:

```
/(http|ftp|https)://[w-_]+(.[w-_]+)+([w-.,@?^=%&:/~+#]*[w-@?^=%&/~+#])?/
```

- The original `[\w\-_]` means "match any word (alphanumeric) character, a hyphen or an underscore".
- `[w-_]` means "match any character between "w" and "_".

But "w" actually comes *after* "_" (look at an ASCII/UTF-8 character table) meaning it's an *invalid range* in the *character class* ("character class" = "collection of characters to match")

Comment: Answer with great explanation, Thanks very much